# Gmail Login doesn't work after enabling Google Play App Signing

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app on Google Play and now I see that Gmail login doesn't work. I have enabled Google Play App Signing and now it gave me App signing and Upload certificates. Where I have to put the new SHA1 code in Google Play developer Console so that Gmail login works?

Comment: AFAIK, Google Play App Signing overwrites your key with its own and stores it on Google Play. So your  GmailAPI project credentials are no longer valid cause app has new signature, hence new SHA1. Paste SHA1 from the signing supplied by Google in your GmailAPI project credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set SHA key for new sign apk in your developer console.

In detail. You have to create new SHA key for your sign apk and that key you have to replace in your good developer console account.

Path for set SHA key console>your projects> credential

Comment: I added SHA1 code of App Signing certificate to my Firebase console and now it works.

Comment: @Mehul, what do you mean - need to create new SHA? Is not it created and overwritten in your apk by Google Play App Signing? Do not you need to find this new SHA generated by Google Play and use it in the credentials for API your app is using? Am I missing something?